# Not able to see script (VB code) from SSIS script task

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis, ssis-2008, ssis-2005

I have one already developed SSIS application using SQL Server 2005. I'm trying to view the script like below:

```
 Right click -> Edit -> Script -> Design script
```

[normally instade of "Design script" it should come "Edit script". I think, due to SSIS 2005 its like that]

However, its not showing me underline script.Its not showing any error as well.
I have BI studio 2005 installed. However, I can not see VB under(file -> new -> project) if I'm going to create new project. So, do I need a Visual studio version 2005 with VB to be installed to open this?

Is there any other way to see this? OR is there any settings needs to be changed to see this underline script?

Answer (score 0):

Hum I don't know what is causing that error but `Visual Studio BI edition` is enough (and required) to edit all functionality of a SSIS. Including the VB code in the Script Task without the need to install the whole VB environment.

You should really watch about any error reported when you open the solution, especially the "corruption" messages which are usually indicators that Visual Studio cannot decipher the parts of the SSIS that were encrypted (depending of the security model of your SSIS).

You also would want to make sure you've installed the Visual Studio BI for 2005 and not 2008 (or other) since, unlike 'classic' projects, SSIS projects are highly tied with the version of VS BI it was created with.